# Can I break a block {PhotoSet} in tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

Suppose that I have defined 5 custom posts, and in each of them I defined photoset to post multiple photos. But in each of one I only want to execute 1 time and get the 1 photo. So how can I break a photoset block?

```
{block:Photoset}
     <article>
        <span class="break" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"></span>

        <!-- Go through each Photo in the Photoset -->
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
        {/block:Photos}

        {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
        {/block:Caption}
        <p></p>
        <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
    </article>
{/block:Photoset}
```

Something like this:

```
{block:Photoset}
     <article>
        <span class="break" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"></span>

        <!-- Go through each Photo in the Photoset -->
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
        {/block:Photos}

        {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
        {/block:Caption}
        <p></p>
        <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
    </article>

**BREAK HERE??**

{/block:Photoset}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to limit them, but you can *comment them out*:

```
{block:Photoset}
     <article>
        <span class="break" style="padding-bottom: 19px;"></span>

        <!-- Go through each Photo in the Photoset -->
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
            I assume you want the break here
            <!--
        {/block:Photos}
        -->

        {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
        {/block:Caption}
        <p></p>
        <time>{TimeAgo}</time>
    </article>
{/block:Photoset}
```

See that `<!--` before `{/block:Photos}`? That opens an HTML comment right after the first image, so the rest of the images in the loop will be in a comment, invisible. After the loop we close the comment with `-->`. Done, all the images in the photoset after the first one will be hidden.